NSCoding struct and tuple
I've a struct that contains some CGPoint & array of tuple:
typealias MapNode = (color: UIColor, location: CGPoint)

struct MapCollectionNode  {
    var position: CGPoint
    var containedLocations: [MapNode]
}

Then I've an Array consists of MapCollectionNode:
    var nodeCollection = [MapCollectionNode]()

Since NSCoding doesn't support struct and tuple, I had to first break down the nodeCollection as following:
var position = [CGPoint]()
var nodes = [[MapNode]]()
for n in nodeCollection {
    position.append(n.position)
    nodes.append(n.containedLocations)
}

then I had to further break down the tuples within nodes as following:
var color = [SKColor]()
var location = [CGPoint]()

for i in 0..<nodes.count {
    for j in nodes[i] {
        color.append(j.color)
        location.append(j.location)
    }
}

At this point I'm able to encode all the information I needed:
aCoder.encode(position, forKey: "MapClass.position")
aCoder.encode(color, forKey: "MapClass.color")
aCoder.encode(location, forKey: "MapClass.location")

At the time of decoding, I've them all decoded as following:
let position = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey:  "MapClass.position") as? [CGPoint]
let color = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey:  "MapClass.color") as? [SKColor]
let location = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey:  "MapClass.location") as? [CGPoint]

However, I'm stuck on how to put color and location back into nodes (which is a [[MapNode]]). Once that's done I can do the following to rebuild nodeCollection:
for i in 0..< position!.count {
     let nodeCollection = MapCollectionNode(position:  position![i], containedLocations: nodes[i])
self.nodeCollection.append(nodeCollection)
            
} 

Any help would be appreciated.

Please show your actual encode and decode methods in their entirety, so we can see what you're really doing (and what the hard part is supposed to be). It's unclear how you think this is going to work, because a map collection node is a position together with an array of color/location pairs. So it isn't obvious how you think your three (badly named) decoded arrays position, color, and location are supposed to fit together.

If I understand correctly, you seem to have flattened the colors and locations? I think at this point you should just create a class for them and stop using tuples. By the way, have you considered using the Swift Codable APIs?

I did use a class initially and it worked well. However comparing to saved file sizes, the one using a class was almost 5 times larger than the one using tuple. That's why I'm trying to stick with tuple. The reason I use NSCoding is because the code is a part of an SKScene (SpriteKit framework) which conforms to NSCoding.

What's the issue with the size? Is it taking too long?

No that it is taking too long. Each scene has its own save file. There are over 20 scenes in total. if I go with using a class instead of tuple, it would take up more than 160MB to save all scenes whereas it only takes about 40MB with using tuples.

I've figured out where I did wrong. The color and location should be defined as Two-Dimensional Arrays
var color = [[SKColor]]()
var location = [[CGPoint]]()

    for i in 0..< nodes.count {
        var c = [SKColor]()
        var l = [CGPoint]()
        for j in 0..<nodes[i].count {
            c.append(collection[i][j].color)
            l.append(collection[i][j].location)
        }
        color.append(c)
        location.append(l)
    }

With that I have no trouble restore them back to array of [[MapNode]] and then rebuild nodeCollection.
